# StringFormat freezes UI

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I am making a ProgressBar with a TextBlock on top of it to notify the user about the download, I need the TextBlock to be bound to the value of the ProgressBar and formatted through XAML.

Like this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TxtBlock_Download" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
                   TextAlignment="Center" 
                   Foreground="White" Padding="0,2,0,0">
    <!--Updates the textbox by using multibinding-->
     <TextBlock.Text>
         <!--TODO fix the StringFormat -->
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=kk}" StringFormat="{}{}">
            <Binding ElementName="ProgressBar_Download" Path="Value"/>
            <Binding ElementName="ProgressBar_Download" Path="Maximum"/>
        </MultiBinding>         
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

I am also using a separate class to connect the two value and maximum

Like this:

```
class Binding : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values[0] + "/" + values[1].ToString();
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value as string).Split('/');
    }
}
```

But every time I try to format the string using `StringFormat=""` it freezes the UI until the download is complete (The download still works in the background but the program is frozen).

Comment: Are you sure it's the string format and not that the download is running on the UI thread blocking any updates until it finishes?

Comment: Why are you using a `Converter` **and** a `StringFormat`? btw. Since the `ConverBack` method doesn't make a lot of sense, I'd return `Enumerable.Repeat(DependencyProperty.UnsetValue, targetTypes.Length).ToArray()` instead.

Comment: @Adwaenyth I don't know much about threads so I can't really answer that.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Because I am trying to connect the two values of Maximum and the value itself like  "4.9/25.6"

Comment: @JosefLintz The question can easily be answered by removing the TextBlock entirely. Does the Progressbar move? Does your code work when you remove what you think is the cause of your problems?

Comment: @JosefLintz You can completely remove that `StringFormat` - it does nothing. If ti was `StringFormat={} Progress: {0}` for example, I'd understand, but the way it is now ...

Comment: The problem start when I set the `StringFormat=""` to even the simplest value like `StringFormat="{{}"` it freezes the ui but anything else runs ok

Comment: @JosefLintz Try removing it completely. If you don't intend to change the value your converter returned any further, you don't need it.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer removing it completely works it just shows the entire decimal number of the double I need string format to only show the first two numbers after the dot

Comment: You can't format a number that was converted to a string. If your converter returns e.g. `23.435345/55.34335` no amount of string formatting can change that.

Comment: Format the numbers in your converter and forget about StringFormat. e.g.: `return ((double)values[0]).ToString("f2") + "/" + ((double)values[1]).ToString("f2");`

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer thanks this is exactly what I was looking for if you can show that as answer so it would be easier for users to search for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can't format numbers that have already been converted to string I recommend you simply rewrite your converter (since you already have one) to take care of all the formatting you need:

```
class MyAwesomeProgressConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((double)values[0]).ToString("f2") + "/" + ((double)values[1]).ToString("f2");
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Enumerable.Repeat(DependencyProperty.UnsetValue, targetTypes.Length).ToArray()
    }
}
```

---

Also:

- You don't need `ConvertBack`. Throw an Exception or return an Array of `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` or `Binding.DoNothing`.
- Don't name your Converter `Binding` - that might cause ambiguities

Comment: Yeah I know, (naming.. right ?) It was just as a test to make sure it works first

Comment: @JosefLintz Yep - I'm not a fan of overly long class names either but they should at least not conflict with existing ones.